# How to collect a stream of pairs in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How to collect a stream of pairs in kotlin?
So in Java, I usually do:

```
Stream.of("1", "2", "3").map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, x)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
```

However in Kotlin,

```
Stream.of("1", "2", "3").map{ x -> x to x }
```

returns a Stream of Pairs and i can't find a way to collect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin, it's more natural to use `listOf()` rather than Java's `Stream.of()`. Once you have a `List<Pair>`, you can use the `.toMap()` extension to turn them into a Map!

```
val myMap: Map<String, String> = listOf("1", "2", "3").map{ it to it }.toMap()
```

There is also the `.associate()` function on `List` that will just create a map for you, given a lambda:

```
val myMap2: Map<String, String> = listOf("1", "2", "3").associate { it to it }
```

That one seems cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but basically after my map is done, I get a `Stream<Pair<String, String>>` and that doesn't seem to have a toMap method. For ex: listOf(Pair("1", "2"), Pair("3", "4")).stream().map { it -> it }

Comment: You don't need to keep inserting `stream`.

Comment: If you have a List<Pair> already... `listOf(Pair("1", "2") ... ).toMap()`

Comment: If you have statically defined key/valyes then `mapOf("1" to "2", "3" to "4")` will be good choice for you

Comment: @Todd Got it. Using stream was the issue. Didn't realize in Kotlin you don't need to use stream

Answer (score -1):

Since you use the list element itself as key, using [associateWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-with.html) would make the code even more concise:

```
val myMap = listOf("1", "2", "3").associateWith{ it }
```

Result:

> {1=1, 2=2, 3=3}